# Make text on a div run a different function onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looping over some data and rendering it into the browser like

```
{paymentPeriods.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`payment-card ${
          type.toLowerCase() == item.type.toLowerCase()
            ? "payment-card-active"
            : ""
        }`}
        key={index}
        onClick={() => {
          setPaymentPeriodValue(item);
        }}
      >
        <div
          className={`payment-card-title ${
            type.toLowerCase() == item.type.toLowerCase()
              ? "payment-card-title-active"
              : ""
          }`}
        >
          {item.type.toLowerCase() == "annual"
            ? "ANNUAL"
            : "MONTHLY"}
        </div>
        <div className="payment-card-body">
          //Some dummy text
        </div>
        {item.type.toLowerCase() != "annual" && (
          <p className="installments_check" onClick={()=>alert('123')}>
            Verifique todas as outras parcelas
          </p>
        )}
      </div>

    </>
  );
})}
```

As you can see upon clicking on div, I am running a function

```
setPaymentPeriodValue(item);
```

which is used to set the div as active so that it is highlighted upon click and the info get stored in my react state locally, now there is also a text inside my div which i am showing like

```
{item.type.toLowerCase() != "annual" && (
  <p className="installments_check" onClick={()=>alert('123')}>
    Verifique todas as outras parcelas
  </p>
)}
```

So on clicking on this text (it is inside the main div) the alert is seen by the user but then it also runs setPaymentPeriodValue function which sets div to the active state, and i do not want this as i only need to show the alert on click of the text

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `stopPropagation` method of the `Event` (this method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements). like this:

```
{
   item.type.toLowerCase() != "annual" && ( 
    <p className="installments_check" onClick={(e)=>{ alert('123'); e.stopPropagation(); } }> Verifique todas as outras parcelas </p> 
  )
}
```